# One of my list elements is positioned lower than the rest even though they all have same height

Tags: html, css

For some reason one of my list elements is 1 pixel lower than the rest even though they all have same height. You'll see that the list element containing the image and username is 1 pixel lower than the rest of them. I've tried quite a lot in my CSS and nothing seems to solve this so it's probably something I don't fully understand.

HTML5

```
<section class="header">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <nav class="navigation">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="{{ route('home') }}">Images</a></li>
                        <li><a href="{{ route('albums') }}">Albums</a></li>
                        <li><a href="{{ route('tags') }}">Tags</a></li>
                        @auth
                        <li><a href="{{ route('upload') }}">Upload</a></li>
                        <li class='logOut'><a href="{{ route('logout') }}">Logout</a></li>
                        <li class='navUsernameLi'><img class='navProfilePicture' src='{{url("storage/uploads/profile_pictures/".Auth::user()->profile_picture)}}'><p class='navUsernameP'>{{ Auth::user()->username }}</p></li>
                        @endauth
                        @guest
                        <li id='signUp'>Sign Up</li>
                        <li id="logIn">Log In</li>
                        @endguest
                        <li><a href="{{ route('contact') }}">Contact Us</a></li>
                        @auth
                        @if (Auth::user()->hasRole('Admin'))
                            <li><a href="{{ route('admin') }}">Admin Panel</a></li>
                        @endif
                        @endauth
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </section>
```

CSS3

```
.navigation {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #151719;
}

.navigation > ul {
  display: inline;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.navigation > ul li {
  display: inline-block;

}

.navigation > ul li a {
    font-size: 16px;
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0 0px 0;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-decoration: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.navUsernameLi {
    float: right;
}
.navUsernameP {
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
}
.navProfilePicture {
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 50px;
}
.navUsernameLi {
    float: right;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}
.navUsernameP {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 50px;
}
.navProfilePicture {
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 50px;
    height: 24px;
    width: 24px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 50px;
}
```

Here's the website if anyone wanna see for themselves - http://www.onyx.space/ . Log in using Admin for username and password. You'll see that the list element containing the image and username is 1 pixel lower than the rest of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is generated by  `line-height: 50px;` of `.navUsernameLi`, remove it and they will align:

```
.navUsernameLi {
    float: right;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    /*line-height: 50px;*/
    height: 50px;
}
```

Already having `vertical-align: middle` is enough, line-height overwrites the positioning aspect of the element.